# How to find if element with specific id exists or not

Tags: javascript, dom

In my JavaScript I want to check whether the element with specific id is exist or not, I tried it with 2 ways

1).

```
var myEle = document.getElementById("myElement");
if(myEle  == null){
   var myEleValue= document.getElementById("myElement").value;
}
```

2).

```
if(getElementById("myElement")){
    var myEleValue= document.getElementById("myElement").value;
}
```

but it gives same error as below -

> Object expected

Comment: It's `document.getElementById()`

Comment: In your 1st case you're saying if the element is null then get it's value, you should be checking that if it's not null (or rather if it's truthy as you're doing in case 2). The other thing is you need to use `document.getElementById()`

Comment: yea I did same in my code, here its by mistake

Comment: just change to `myEle != null`, `document.getElementById()` returns null if an element with the required id was not found (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: @AmitaPatil you must not edit the question to an answer! You must keep the code that originated the problem!

Answer (score 201, accepted):

```
var myEle = document.getElementById("myElement");

if(myEle) {
    var myEleValue= myEle.value;
}
```

the return of getElementById is null if an element is not actually present inside the dom, so your if statement will fail, because null is considered a false value

Comment: You mean document.getElementById("myElement") this returns boolean value ?

Comment: use  `if(myEle!=null){}`

Comment: @AmitaPatil no it doesn't, but you can check if a variable is defined only checking it in an if, if the variable myEle isn't defined the if will choose the else block of code

Comment: You should also consider wrapping that inside the load event callback as if the DOM is not loaded the if will never be executed even if the element will be there!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I just modified his piece of code, if the problem is on load please edit the question with other code to show us what is your problem

Comment: Ok so yeah. Where exactly do I put this code? It is not like it will execute automatically when the elements are added I mean it's not Jetpack Compose. What do you say to that? Thanks,

Comment: Well, it depends on the moment in which you need to verify the element exist, on window load or inside a function that need to check that.

Comment: How come it wasn't required of you to use .length for myEle?

Comment: @klewis getElementById returns a single HTMLElement or null, so you can't verify a length, maybe you are confused with querySelectorAll?

Answer (score 15):

You can simply use `if(yourElement)`

```js
var a = document.getElementById("elemA");
var b = document.getElementById("elemB");

if(a)
  console.log("elemA exists");
else
  console.log("elemA does not exist");
  
if(b)
  console.log("elemB exists");
else
  console.log("elemB does not exist");
```

```html
<div id="elemA"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

**getElementById**

Return Value:   An Element Object, representing an element with the specified ID. Returns null if no elements with the specified ID exists
see: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

**Truthy vs Falsy**

In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered  true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN). see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

When the dom element is not found in the `document` it will return `null`. null is a Falsy and can be used as `boolean expression` in the if statement.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("myElement");
if(myElement){
  // Element exists
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. Never really understood Falsy before!

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('yourId')
```

is the correct way.

the document refers the HTML document that is loaded in the DOM.

and it searches the id using the function getElementById()
which takes a parameter of the id of an element

Solution will be :

```
var elem = (document.getElementById('myElement'))? document.getElementById('myElement').value : '';

/* this will assign a value or give you and empty string */
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify which object you're calling getElementById from. In this case you can use document. You also can't just call .value on any element directly. For example if the element is textbox .value will return the value, but if it's a div it will not have a value.

You also have a wrong condition, you're checking

> if (myEle == null)

which you should change to

> if (myEle != null)

```
var myEle = document.getElementById("myElement");
if(myEle != null) { 
    var myEleValue= myEle.value; 
}
```

Comment: better use `myEle.value` inside if block.

Answer (score 3):

Use typeof for elements checks.

```
if(typeof(element) === 'undefined')
{
// then field does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if( document.getElementById("myElement") ){
   console.log('exists');
}
```

or shorter way

```
if( document.querySelector("#myElement") ){}
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me to check if element exits

```
let element = document.getElementById("element_id");
if (typeof(element) !== 'undefined' && element!== null)
{
    //content
}
```