# Retrieve content of array used on a different JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a first HTML page, where I do a drag and drop and put the file got with the drag and drop, on the firebase storage. When I finished the drag and drop and the sending of the files to the firebase storage, I have created a double array, where I put all the information that I need, so, the name of each files and their downdoable link aswell.

And I need to re-use this same array, on a second HTML page. How can I do it?

Comment: We would need waaaaay more information to give a relevant answer, it would also be worth including a minimal example of what you have so far.

Comment: Try to save it in LocalStorage on the First page and retrieve it on the Second.

Comment: I hope it helps ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357553/how-do-i-store-an-array-in-localstorage

Comment: I understood how it works, but how can i use this localstorage in a differant JS file ?? :( @AnjanKumarGJ

Comment: I just tried this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-and-set-variable-values-from-one-javascript-file-to-another-javascript-file-using-local-storage but i already get null on my variable on the b.js file.... ;( @IvanBurnaev

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are in same file or in different file if you are using localstorage

Comment: is your first page and second page are in same domain? If yes you can go ahead with local storage

Comment: i think yes, this is two differant html file but they are located in the localhsot @GangadharJannu

Comment: Set:
`sessionStorage.setItem("array", yourArray);`
Retrieve:
`sessionStorage.getItem("array");` link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sessionStorage`

Set:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("array", yourArray);
```

Retrieve:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("array");
```

link: [w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp](http://w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp)