# PHP print message when a div is present on specific page

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I am trying to print a message (link) through PHP if a div is present on a page. Basically the div is present on some product pages on an ecommerce website, while it is not present on other product pages. The ecommerce is a Woocommerce and that's why I am using Woo hooks in the code.

Basically I get nothing in return (even when visiting pages where the div is present). What am I missing?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'size_guide_display', 15);
function size_guide_display() {
    $sizeguide = $html->find("div#tab-SizeChart_tab");
    if ($sizeguide) :
        echo '<a href="#tab-SizeChart_tab" title="Storleksguide" class="size_guide_link">Storleksguide</a>';
    endif;
}
```

I'll be very happy for any reply :-) Pretty novice with PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: I would probably use Javascript to do this.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton how would you do it?

Comment: Use javascript to check if the element exists on the page and then display the message.

Comment: If I am novice with PHP you should see my JS skills :-) Wouldn't know how to write that code. Thanks anyway, will do some Google searches for it

Comment: Should be pretty simple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526032/how-to-find-if-element-with-specific-id-exists-or-not

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'size_guide_display', 15);
function size_guide_display() {
    echo 'if(document.getElementById("calq")!='undefined')
{
    // Not sure how to properly print the link tag within javascript, advice?
} ';
}

Would this do?

Comment: No. Javascript is separate from PHP, don't use PHP to echo it. And wrap it in <script> tags. Look up some simple Javascript tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the information you've provided I guess using JavaScript on the client-side would be your way to go.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const sizeChartTabEle = document.querySelector("div#tab-SizeChart_tab")
    const storleksGuideLinkEle = document.createElement("a")
    storleksGuideLinkEle.title = "Storleksguide"
    storleksGuideLinkEle.href = "#tab-SizeChart_tab"
    storleksGuideLinkEle.classList.add("size_guide_link")
    storleksGuideLinkEle.innerText = "Storleksguide"
    sizeChartTabEle?.append(storleksGuideLinkEle)
})
```

This code creates an event listener `DOMContentLoaded` (see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414766/15484481) to learn more about it, speaking very basic - it waits for your contents being loaded) and executes the part in the curly brackets.

Your `div#tab-SizeChart_tab` is queried and afterwards appended by a newly created `a` element `storleksGuideLinkEle`.

If you make sure this code is only executed on pages that you need it, this should do the job.